# What does it mean if a function commutes with its adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean if a function "commutes with its adjoint"?

A matrix, $A$ is self-adjoint if $A = A^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $A$ commutes with its adjoint is to say that $AA^* = A^*A$. This condition is called "normality", and it is equivalent to the existence of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$.